# How to use FsLexYacc with Visual Studio 2022 in F#?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, fslex

I decided to use FsLexYacc for parsing in F#.

So I downloaded it with the NuGet package in Visual Studio, I have no idea how to use it.

[This link](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/fslex.html) says "You then add FsLex and FsYacc entries like this: <code>", where do I add this code?

And I don't even know where to put Lexer.fsl.

I would like to know the procedure for creating a project using FsLexYacc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small sample project [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsLexYacc/tree/master/tests/LexAndYaccMiniProject) and documentation [here](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/index.html) that should be enough to get you started. You add the `FsLex` and `FsYacc` entries to the `.fsproj` project file. It looks like you put `Lexer.fsl` in the same directory as your F# source code (e.g. `Program.fs`).

Comment: Thank you!
I cloned it from git and was able to run it without error.